# std::vector constructed with initializer_list not behaving as expected

Tags: c++, g++, stdvector, initializer-list

The following code is compiled under OpenSUSE Tumbleweed with GCC 9.2.1 20190903 revision 275330

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> datos = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    std::cout << "DEBUG: vector ";
    for (auto d : datos)
        std::cout << datos[d] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
DEBUG: vector 2 3 4 5 6 0
```

But I was expecting

```
DEBUG: vector 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Yet for this other code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> datos = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    std::cout << "DEBUG: vector ";
    for (auto d : datos)
        std::cout << datos[d] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
DEBUG: vector 1 1 2 3 4 5
```

Command line is `g++-9 test.cc`

Am I missing something? Is this a bug in the compiler?

Answer (score 2):

The value of the variable d in the range-based for loop

```
for (auto d : datos)
        std::cout << datos[d] << ' ';
```

is not an index in the vector. It is a value of the current element of the vector

Just use

```
for (auto d : datos)
        std::cout << d << ' ';
```

For this vector

```
std::vector<double> datos = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

you got the expected result because

`datos[datos[1]]` is equal to 1 that is it is equal to this element

```
std::vector<double> datos = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
                               ^^^
```

`datos[datos[1]]` again yields the same element.

`datos[datos[2]]` is equal to 2 and so on.

If you for example will change the vector like

```
std::vector<double> datos = { 5 };
```

then you will have undefined behavior because `datos[datos[2]]` tries to access memory beyond the allocated memory for the vector's elements.

Without deeping in details this loop

```
for (auto d : datos)
    std::cout << d << ' ';
```

in fact is equivalent to the following

```
for ( auto first = std::begin( datos ); first != std::end( datos ); ++first )
{
    auto d = *first;
    std::cout << d << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Great comprehensive answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something?

You mixed range based for loops with indexing into a vector - instead, pick one style. Fixed example with range-based for loop (which allows you to *directly*  iterate over the elements of a range):

```
for (auto d : datos)
    std::cout << d << ' ';
```

Example with manual indices:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < datos.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << datos[i] << ' ';
```

Answer (score 1):

For a range-based `for` loop, the item is already an int.

Either use range-based `for` loop correctly

```
for (auto d : datos)
    std::cout << d << ' ';
```

Or use traditional loop

```
for (size_t d = 0; d < datos.size(); ++d)
    std::cout << datos[d] << ' ';
```